# Auto create primary key in table 1 when new foreign key in table 2?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, relational-database

Consider the two tables below - one holds the users and the other the transactions associated with the users. The userID column in the Transactions table is a foreign key of the userID column in the Users table. My question: if a new userID appears in the Transaction table, is it possible to automatically create a new row for this user in the User's table to avoid a foreign key constraint violation? What would be the best way to achieve this?

Users:

```
|   userID  |   name    |
-------------------------
|   123456  |   John    |
|   234567  |   Sarah   |
-------------------------
```

Transactions:

```
|   time    |   userID  |   name    |   amount  |
-------------------------------------------------
|   12:30   |   345678  |   Roy     |   $250    |  <-- New user
|   10:00   |   123456  |   John    |   $100    |
|   09:45   |   234567  |   Sarah   |   $300    |
|   09:30   |   123456  |   John    |   $200    |
|   07:00   |   234567  |   Sarah   |   $501    |
```

Comment: How can you tell the name of the new user if you only know the numeric ID?

Comment: The name is in the Transactions table. Also, it could potentially be left blank if need be - the important part of the User table is the unique userID.

Comment: trigger before insert may be helpful in your case.

Comment: There is a problem with your database design. The user name is redundant in the transactions table and should not be there. The proper way to proceed is: 1) search the user in the user table 2) If it isn't there, insert it 3) insert a row in the transaction table.